# Paste Euler project image in profile

Tags: support, profile-page, images

I'm trying add Euler Project image into my profile by specifying its URL in img form (https://projecteuler.net/profile/Andremoniy.png). But it gives me error:

> Failed to upload image; the format is not supported

Of course, I can save it to disk, reformat and upload. But it is not convenient. Why isn't system able to upload this picture?

Furthermore, is any method to automatically update this picture in my profile or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using below markdown it is working correctly for me.

> [![enter image description here][1]][1]
>
> [1]: https://projecteuler.net/profile/Andremoniy.png

Copy paste above in your profile and then check.

Comment: Great! Thanks. What about auto-update of the picture?

Comment: The problem is in the uploader, not the markdown.

Comment: (BTW, I'm wondering, how is downvoter and why?)

Comment: @PatrickHofman this question is not about "profile-image" (and I didn't mention such kind of term in my question), and it perfectly works

Comment: @PatrickHofman I think op is talking about his profile description?

Comment: Auto update depends on the link you provided e.g. when the image is changed on link you provided the image on your description will also change.